# GroovyClassLoader using method recompile removeClassCacheEntry

Tags: groovy

How can i use these methods

```
protected Class     recompile(URL source, String className, Class oldClass)
```

(Re)Compiles the given source.

```
protected void  removeClassCacheEntry(String name)
```

removes a class from the class cache.

in my program using GroovyClassLoader

Comment: in fact GroovyScriptEngine can do it really good,but it seems that ,it can't compile groovy with interdependent relationship

Comment: yes i agree then whats the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods are protected, becaue you are not really supposed to call them directly and only if you need to extend the GroovyClassLoader (GCL) with special logic. GCL does also handle only simple cases of recompilation, it cannot handle recompilation dependencies. You are supposed to use GroovyScriptEngine for these kind of things.